# Reuse of redirect-action in struts.xml?

Tags: struts2

I have multiple actions that after completion redirect back to a general page (showStuff). I'm looking for a way to NOT repeat the list of parameters for every redirect-action.

What I have is this:

```
<action name="doThis" class="com.domain.package.MyAction" method="doThis">
    <result type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">showStuff</param>
        <param name="parse">true</param>
        <param name="selectedYear">${selectedYear}</param>
        <param name="selectedMonth">${selectedMonth}</param>
        <param name="selectedDay">${selectedDay}</param>
    </result>
</action>
<action name="doThat" class="com.domain.package.MyAction" method="doThat">
    <result type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">showStuff</param>
        <param name="parse">true</param>
        <param name="selectedYear">${selectedYear}</param>
        <param name="selectedMonth">${selectedMonth}</param>
        <param name="selectedDay">${selectedDay}</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

I would like to keep the parameter list within the showStuff action definition, and then use is like so:

```
<action name="doThis" class="com.domain.package.MyAction" method="doThis">
    <result type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">showStuff</param>
    </result>
</action>
<action name="doThat" class="com.domain.package.MyAction" method="doThat">
    <result type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">showStuff</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: its quite possible what you are trying to do.are you facing any specific issue?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi I didnt understand how is it possible. `selectedYear`, `selectedMonth` etc params are from the class `MyAction`, then wouldn't they be lost on redirection without declaring them? Am I wrong?

Comment: yes, i mis read the question, redirection will clear value-stack and nre request response object will be in place

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options.

Honestly, I'd skip most of my workarounds, and put them into session.

Once they're in session, create an interceptor and interface (`Dateable` or something). In the interceptor check the session for the variables (see below) and if the action is a `Dateable`, set them on the action, and you're done.

Another option is to encapsulate these variables as a date and either use the built-in converter or use your own converter. Then you'd only need a single parameter. This option would work with the interceptor idea as well.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it is very much possible. This is how you do it:

Add a global result:

```
<global-results>
    <result name="show-stats" type="redirectAction">    
        <param name="actionName">showStats</param>
        <param name="parse">true</param>
        <param name="selectedYear">${selectedYear}</param>
        <param name="selectedMonth">${selectedMonth}</param>
        <param name="selectedDay">${selectedDay}</param>
  </result>
```

And then for the actions:

```
<action name="doThis" class="com.domain.package.MyAction" method="doThis"/>
<action name="doThat" class="com.domain.package.MyAction" method="doThat"/>
```

Finally in the java code, just:

```
return "show-stats";
```

And you're done.

As a sidenote, why do I have to spend so much time trying to adhere to the very basic DRY principle? Aren't all these frameworks supposed to .. you know.. simplify stuff? Just wondering...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem with an endless list of params getting longer and longer, repeated in several places. What I ended up doing was that I created an external file and declared it in struts.xml as an entity then included it instead of repeating all the params

This goes in the doctype tag

```
<!ENTITY referenceName SYSTEM "fileName">
```

Then you include it like so

```
&referenceName;
```